# MongoDB: Replacing a dictionary from subdocuments in an array field

Tags: mongodb

Assuming I have a Mongo Collection of Books and I want to replace all the genre_tag of Science Fiction with Sci-Fi instead: How would I go about writing the update operation in Mongo_DB.

```
Book Collection
[
  {
    "title": "The Adventures of Alice in Wonderland",
    "author": "Lewis Carroll",
    "publication_year": 1865,
    "Books.Tags": [
      {
        "genre_tag": "Fantasy",
        "genre_id": "FAN001",
        "date_created": "2023-07-23",
        "person_created": "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "genre_tag": "Adventure",
        "genre_id": "ADV001",
        "date_created": "2023-07-23",
        "person_created": "John Doe"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "To Kill a Mockingbird",
    "author": "Harper Lee",
    "publication_year": 1960,
    "Books.Tags": [
      {
        "genre_tag": "Classic",
        "genre_id": "CLS002",
        "date_created": "2023-07-23",
        "person_created": "Jane Smith"
      },
      {
        "genre_tag": "Drama",
        "genre_id": "DRM002",
        "date_created": "2023-07-23",
        "person_created": "Jane Smith"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy",
    "author": "Douglas Adams",
    "publication_year": 1979,
    "Books.Tags": [
      {
        "genre_tag": "Science Fiction",
        "genre_id": "SCI003",
        "date_created": "2023-07-23",
        "person_created": "Sam Johnson"
      },
      {
        "genre_tag": "Comedy",
        "genre_id": "CMD001",
        "date_created": "2023-07-23",
        "person_created": "Sam Johnson"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Pride and Prejudice",
    "author": "Jane Austen",
    "publication_year": 1813,
    "Books.Tags": [
      {
        "genre_tag": "Romance",
        "genre_id": "ROM004",
        "date_created": "2023-07-23",
        "person_created": "Emily Brown"
      },
      {
        "genre_tag": "Drama",
        "genre_id": "DRM002",
        "date_created": "2023-07-23",
        "person_created": "Emily Brown"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Replacement Label:

sci_fi_label = {
        "genre_tag": "Sci Fi",
        "genre_id": "SCIFI001",
        "date_created": "2023-07-23",
        "person_created": "Sam Johnson"
      }
```

I have tried adding the tags directly with addToSet which is possible but for the deletion of the Science Fiction Label I am not familiar with whether I can just pull and delete the specific tag.

```
{
  "genre_tag": "Science Fiction",
  "genre_id": "SCI003",
  "date_created": "2023-07-23",
  "person_created": "Sam Johnson"
}
```